# How Spring @RequestBody works? and how @RequestBody map json to customize object?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to know how **@RequestBody** map works for **json to object**? Which mapper it use?

Comment: Hi @Shubham, welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be nice if you do little own research before putting query here. If things are not clarified people are here to update that.

Comment: Hi @SwaritAgarwal , I research about my problem but couldn't find sufficient information that would solve problem. So, I asked

Comment: In my problem , I was using lombok and JsonIgnore (tried multiple version as well as type(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore and org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore))in few projects. In some project it works fine but in some its not. So , I think to checkout how @RequestBody works. So, that I can verify it . But didn't get appropriate information about it.

Comment: Its good you have done some analysis.. Please provide that information here

Answer (score 0):

When Spring goes to generate an argument for a @RequestBody parameter, it loops through the HttpMessageConverter instances, checks if that instance HttpMessageConverter#canRead the content type given in the request and can generate an instance of the parameter type. If it can, Spring will use that HttpMessageConverter to produce an argument. If it can't, Spring will skip it and try the next instance, until it runs out. At which point, it will throw an exception.

*-copied*

The Default Message Converters
By default, the following HttpMessageConverters instances are pre-enabled:

- ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter – converts byte arrays
- StringHttpMessageConverter – converts Strings
- ResourceHttpMessageConverter – converts org.springframework.core.io.Resource for any type of octet stream
- SourceHttpMessageConverter – converts javax.xml.transform.Source
- FormHttpMessageConverter – converts form data to/from a
- MultiValueMap.
- Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter – converts Java objects to/from XML (added only if JAXB2 is present on the classpath)
- MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter – converts JSON (added only if Jackson 2 is present on the classpath)
- MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter – converts JSON (added only if Jackson is present on the classpath)
- AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter – converts Atom feeds (added only if Rome is present on the classpath)
- RssChannelHttpMessageConverter – converts RSS feeds (added only if Rome is present on the classpath)